# Proof vectors are eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonality

Let $k <n$ and $v_1, v_2,...,v_k \in \mathbb{R^n}$ be not-zero vectors, orthogonal relative to the standard inner product on $\mathbb{R^n}$, where the vectors of $\mathbb{R^n}$ are columnvectors. Let $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_k \in \mathbb{R}$ and say: $$A = \lambda_1v_1v_1^{T} + ... + \lambda_kv_kv_k^{T} \in \mathbb{R^{n\times n}}$$

$a)$ Proof that $v_1, v_2,...,v_k$ are eigenvectors of $A$.

$$$$b) Proof $dim(E_0) \geq n - k$ with $ E_0$ being the eigenspace of the eigenvalue $0$.

(For b I would think this has something to do with the kernel and that I should look at $vct({v_1, v_2,...,v_k})^{\perp}$)

I'm really not good in these proof questions and I would appreciate if someone could say what goes on in your mind when solving these types of problems and give me a head start in this specific question.

Comment: For (a) just look at what happens when you apply $A$ to each of the $v_i$s, remember linearity! Hint: If all the $v_i$'s are orthogonal then what happens to terms with $v_i^Tv_j$ when $i\neq j$?

Comment: Then it equals to zero but $i=j$ in the question so I'm a bit confused

Comment: $i=j$ for only one of the terms in the sum and the rest of the terms are zero like you said. The only nonzero term is $Av_i=\lambda_iv_iv_i^Tv_i$ and what does $v_i^Tv_i$ simplify to (i.e. when $i=j$)? From this you should be able to see that each of the $v_i$s is an eigenvector (recall the definition if that helps).

Comment: That equals to 1! That is actually not that difficult, you just transform it into the definition and go from there. Someone just gave the answer but your explanation was equally helpful. Thank you.

Comment: actually its only equal to 1 if the set of vectors are also orthonormal, otherwise their inner product will be proportional to the norm as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: as for part (b) you should be able to figure this out using the rank-nullity theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem

Comment: Could you give a hint how to start?

Comment: the nullity is the dimension of the kernel. The kernel is the same thing as the $0$-eigenspace $E_0$. If the $k$ vectors that make up the linear operator $A$ above are non-zero and orthogonal then the rank (the dimension of the image of $A$) must be $k$.

Answer (score 1):

For all $i\in \{1,\cdots, k\}, Av_i = \lambda_1v_1v_1^Tv_i + \cdots + \lambda_iv_iv_i^Tv_i + \cdots + \lambda_kv_1v_k^Tv_i$

$\lambda_iv_iv_i^Tv_i  = \lambda \|v_i\|^2 v_i$

If $j\ne k,$
$\lambda_jv_jv_j^Tv_i = 0$ as $v_i$ orthogonal to $v_j$ implies $v_j^Tv_i = 0$

$Av_i = \lambda \|v_i\|^2 v_i$ making $v_i$ an eigenvector.